# Obtain maximum likelihood estimate

Tags: statistics

The number of dropped connections per call follows a Poisson distribution. From four calls, the number of dropped connections is $2,\,0,\,3,\,1$.
Obtain the maximum likelihood estimate that the next two calls will be completed without any accidental drops.

I know the maximum likelihood estimate of $\lambda$ is $1.5$.
I think I am supposed to use this formula:
$$f(x|\lambda) = \frac{\lambda^x e^{-\lambda}}{x!}$$

However, I do not know what $x$ should be.  The answer should be $0.0498$.

Comment: You need some assumption about the relative duration of the calls, such as all of them being the same length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

x is the number of dropped connections, right? So $x=0$ for no dropped connections.

Comment: Then that would be e^-1.5 = 0.223. However, the answer should be 0.0498

Comment: Squared (since there are two calls).